# Docker Desktop Linux Container reachable from other PC

Tags: networking, docker-desktop

I am new to Docker and using Docker Desktop on a Windows 10 machine. I was able to two containers running with postgres and pgadmin4 AND I am able to manage the postgres database(s) through pgadmin4 called up by localhost:port in my browser.

Now I try to find a way to call this container from another PC in the same network. After two days of research I still have not find a working sample to do so. Does anybody has a concept to do this?

Thanks in Advance

Michael

Answer (score 0):

I found the answer myself and it is pretty straight forward. Simply use the IP of the Docker Host machine i.e. 123.456.0.7 and the host port wich is mapped to the container (i.e. 123.456.0.7:8080).

... moving along the docker roads

Michael